# Assign parent 's instance variable by using super keyword in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, super

I have 2 class in Java

```
1. public class A {
2.     public int i = 1;
3. }
4. 
5. public class B extends A {
6.     int i = 2;
7.     public void print() {
8.         super.i = 3;
9.         A obj = new B();
10.        System.out.println(obj.i);
11.        System.out.println(this.i);
12.        System.out.println(super.i);
13.    }
14.
15.    public static void main(String [] args) {
16.        new B().print();
17.    }
18.}
```

When I run above code it print

```
1
2
3
```

So I want to know why line 10 and 12 print different output? I think because I assign super.i = 3 and create new object of A, the result should be 3, 2, 3. Please help me

Comment: `super` refers to `this` instance, as an instance of its superclass. `obj` is a different object from `this`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two `B` objects in your program, the one created by main(), and the one created by the print() method in that first object.

Each `B` has its own instance of `i`.

Only the first `B` has `i` set to 3, and `obj` refers to the second `B`.